Flask-Security: CSRF SESSION Token Missing in Angular Request
I have a Flask application using the Flask-Security extension. Here's how my app is initialized:
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
CORS(app)
CSRFProtect(app)

app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", 'pf9Wkove4IKEAXvy-cQkeDPhv9Cb3Ag-wyJILbq_dFw')
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = os.environ.get("SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT", '146585145368132386173505678016728509634')
app.config["SECURITY_EMAIL_VALIDATOR_ARGS"] = {"check_deliverability": False}

app.teardown_appcontext(lambda exc: db_session.close())

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore(db_session, User, Role)
app.security = Security(app, user_datastore)

I also have another Angular-based app communicating with the Flask app. In the OnInit function, I ensure a CSRF token is provided:
this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/login")
  .subscribe({
    next: (response: any) => {
      let crsftoken = response.response.csrf_token;
      console.log("CRFS TOKEN aus GET" + crsftoken);
      localStorage.setItem("crsftoken", crsftoken);
    },
    // ...
  });

This works fine, but when I try to log in a user using a login form, the CSRF token doesn't seem to be included in the request. Here's the code executed when the form is submitted:
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('email', this.loginForm.controls.username.value || "");
formData.append('password', this.loginForm.controls.password.value || "");
this.http.post("http://localhost:5000/login", formData)
  .subscribe({
    next: (response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
    },
    // ...
  });

When I execute this code, I receive a "Bad Request" response with the message "The CSRF session token is missing." It seems like the session token isn't being sent with the request, but I'm not sure why.
During the first call to the GET method for "http://localhost:5000/login", I can see the session in the response and in the Set-Cookie header. However, it doesn't seem to be stored in the browser. As a result, it's not sent with the subsequent request.
I tried the same using POSTMAN - and there it works?!
Added: Of course I am usingen an HTTP-Interceptor to put in the Csrf-Token in the header with each request, see:
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let crsftoken = localStorage.getItem('crsftoken');
    let headers = request.headers;
    headers = headers.set("X-CSRF-TOKEN", crsftoken || "");
    request = request.clone({
      headers : headers
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I missunderstand the difference between CSRF token and CSRF session token?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I recommend axios and using the withCredentials param like this response = await axios.get(apiURL, { withCredentials: true });

You can provide the exact error message and capture from your browser's network by selecting your URL, then in the box that opens, select 'headers', so you can see if the 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' header is indeed being added with its respective value.

It is :-)
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, /
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: de,de-DE;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,tr;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 250
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydDQz5cu8PWSI4cyl
Host: localhost:5000
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: ...
X-CSRF-TOKEN: longlongtoken...
sec-ch-ua: ... chrome..
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"

CSRF is implemented mostly in Flask-Login - the token is generated and placed in the session cookie. It is also sent in the form/json as part of the GET to the client. On request the token in the session cookie is compared to the token in the form/header. The server doesn't store the token (unless your using Flask-Session). So no session cookie - and things won't work.

There is a fairly complete writeup on ways to do this at: https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/patterns.html#csrf
One way - take the CSRF token you received and send it as a 'X-CSRF-Token'.
The session cookie does need to be sent- but I'd make sure your CSRF token is being sent correctly first.
The document referenced also explains how to do this with cookies - which Angular (httpclient) has built in support for.

You are right, but I think I already did that. (I added the code snippet to my question, just to make sure.)
But nevertheless - the problem stays ;-)

Have you tried disabling your CORS extension to see if that helps things?

I tried, but then I get another error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

After some research I found out, that Flask Security too isn't so much used as I thought. There are other and more modern plugins, which can be used.
I tried Flask-JWT-Extended for the moment and it works pretty well.
BUT: I also managed, what the solution to my question is!
It is pretty simple. When you do sth. like this:
this.http.get<{ message: string }>('http://localhost:5000/protected').subscribe(...

this won't work. Try this instead:
this.http.get<{ message: string }>('http://localhost:5000/protected', { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(

It took me a while to get to that point and I still have no idea, why this must be used - but it is like it is.
Thanks to all of you for trying to help me!
